# python's trackback error - using pymssql

Tags: python, pymssql

am trying to execute the below code using python 2.5.2. The script is establishing the connection and creating the table, but then its failing with the below error.

The script

```
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(host='10.103.8.75', user='mo', password='the_password', database='SR_WF_MODEL')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE persons(id INT, name VARCHAR(100))')
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO persons VALUES(%d, %s)", \
    [ (1, 'John Doe'), (2, 'Jane Doe') ])
conn.commit()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE salesrep='%s'", 'John Doe')
row = cur.fetchone()
while row:
    print "ID=%d, Name=%s" % (row[0], row[1])
    row = cur.fetchone()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE salesrep LIKE 'J%'")

conn.close()
```

The error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connect_to_mssql.py", line 9, in <module>
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE salesrep='%s'", 'John Doe')
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/pymssql.py", line 126, in execute
    self.executemany(operation, (params,))
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/pymssql.py", line 152, in executemany
    raise DatabaseError, "internal error: %s" % self.__source.errmsg()
pymssql.DatabaseError: internal error: None
```

any suggestions? plus, how do you read the traceback error, anyone can help me understand the error message? how do you read it? bottom up?

Comment: That traceback is a bad joke. If the error is `None`, then why is it complaining?  And yes, tracebacks get read from the bottom up. Each line is the line that called the line below it.

Comment: There is no column `salesrep`, only `name`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are assuming the regular python string interpolation behavior, ie:

```
>>> a = "we should never do '%s' when working with dbs"
>>> a % 'this'
"we should never do 'this' when working with dbs"
```

The `%` operator within the execute method looks like the normal string formatting operator but that is more of a convenience or mnemonic; your code should read:

`cur.execute("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE salesrep=%s", 'John Doe')`

without the quotes, and this will work with names like O'Reilly, and help prevent SQL injection per the database adapter design. This is really what the database adapter is there for -- converting the python objects into sql; it will know how to quote a string and properly escape punctuation, etc. It would work if you did:

```
>>> THING_ONE_SHOULD_NEVER_DO = "select * from table where cond = '%s'"
>>> query = THING_ONE_SHOULD_NEVER_DO % 'john doe'
>>> query
"select * from table where cond = 'john doe'"
>>> cur.execute(query)
```

but this is bad practice.